# How two EOS nodes on two diffrent instances of aws can communicate with each other through an EOS private chain?

Tags: nodeos, block-producer, blockchains, eosio.system, block.one

I have setup node on each of two aws instance i.e  two nodes on diffrent aws instance , thus created a private blockchain on both of the instances . Now how can i make them communicate with each other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nodes cannot communicate with each other directly but both the nodes can communicate with the chain or genesis node. you have to just add IP and port of the genesis node into the -p2p-peer-address field of .conf file of the node.

Comment: This is the exact answer i was looking for, thanks man!